# how to matching "not" with more chars in java regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex

in java regex,use `[^x]` to matching "not" with one char.

i want to know,how to matching more chars not?

i using `[^789]`,it's not right.

```
    String text="aa(123)bb(456)cc(789)dd(78)";
    text=text.replaceAll("\\([^789].*?\\)","");

    System.out.println(text);
```

i want get result is:

```
aabbcc(789)dd
```

how to fix my regex pattern?

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"\\((?!789\\)).*?\\)"
```

Explanation:

```
\\(     Match a literal open parenthesis "("
(?!     Start negative lookahead
789\\)  Match literal "789)"
)       End lookahead
.*?     Match any characters (non-greedy)
\\)     Match a literal close parenthesis ")"
```

If the pattern inside the negative lookahead matches then negative lookahead fails to match.